# how to change submit button according to list order Java?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

currently i'm in middle of something which is i have a jsp page to get no of beams. In the next page i want next, submit button according to this order

```
if beam = 1 (submit)
if beam = 2 (next, submit)
if beam = 3 (next, next, submit)
if beam = 4 (next, next, next, submit)
```

This is what i did so far but its not working as expected...

```
if(patient.getBeamsno()==1 ){
        map.put("submit");

    }
    else{

    map.put("next");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it should work

```
 if(patient.getBeamsno()==1 ){
        map.put("button","submit");

    }
    else{

    map.put("button","next");
    }
```

Comment: This will work for the first presentation but what about the others ;) Also this is practically a copy of OP's own code.